# How Subtract particular column value by ID and show result in another column for all row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to do this equation like net_PO = PO - total_PO. It will take value **getElementByID**. Result will show in id= **net_PO**. In javascript or jquery I want to do this. Help me. Thanks in advance.

```
<td width="229" class="data"><?php echo $row->total_pen ?></td>
<td width="229" class="data"><?php echo $row->total_rejec ?></td>
<td width="229" class="data" id="PO"><?php echo $row->total_rel ?></td>
<td width="229" class="data" id="total_PO"><?php echo $row->total_po ?></td>
<td width="229" class="data" id="net_PO"></td>
```

I use this javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
 $('#PO').each(function () {
 var PO = $("#PO").html();
 var total_PO = $("#total_PO").html();
 var net_PO = parseFloat(PO) - parseFloat(total_PO);
 $("#net_PO").html(net_PO);
 //alert(net_PO);
  });
});
```

It works only for first row. Not works for all row. All row has same ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using $(document).ready I supose you are including jQuery on your code, try with this:

```
var PO = $("#PO").html();
var total_PO = $("#total_PO").html();
var net_PO = parseFloat(PO) - parseFloat(total_PO);
$("#net_PO").html(net_PO)
```

Comment: Sorry for interrupt. It works only for first row. I've too many rows but it not works for other rows. Can you help me .@Bardo.

Comment: Do cells have the same id in every tr? (they shouldn't, as ids should be unique) If they don't you should use different calls to different ids on each tr... If they do you probably could use a loop to iterate through different rows making the calculation

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript it would look something like this:

```
var PO = parseInt(document.getElementById("PO").innerHTML);
var total_PO = parseInt(document.getElementById("total_PO ").innerHTML);
var net_PO = PO-total_PO;

document.getElementById("net_PO").innerHTML=net_PO;
```